# Is Puppet or Chef suitable for managing very basic server config in a multi tenant environment?

Tags: puppet

This relates to multi-tenant environments such as a small hosting company.

Is Puppet (or similar) a suitable technology for taking care of basic but critical mass changes? For example:

- Updating DNS resolvers (resolv.conf)
- Setting SSH keys
- Updating NTP configuration
- Configuring snmpd
- Deploying monitoring scripts such as SNMP Perl extensions or Nagios scripts

My concerns are around security and invasiveness:

1. I don't want any server to be able to see any config it shouldn't
2. I'm worried that a Puppet master may be vulnerable to attack by a compromised server
3. I don't want Puppet to make any changes which it shouldn't, or revert any manual changes done on the server.

I should caveat this by saying I've never used Puppet in production, only had a quick play around on a test lab, so it's possible I'm thinking about this the wrong way!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Ansible (ansible.cc). May be it is for you. There is no agent running on your clients. It is growing very fast.

Another very good alternative is Salt Stack.

Ansible and Salt are easy to understand, you can use them as a command line tool if you want, like distributed shell.

Comment: I know I asked this a long time ago. You'll be pleased to know thought this was THE answer. We now use Ansible to automatically roll out 10s of servers per day and are managing 1000s in a fire-and-forget style. It's been great for over a year now.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is certainly possible. Deciding if you should do so or not is up to you though.

Regarding your queries:

1) fair enough. The traffic is ssl based, so certificate management is important. Also don't trust any 'facts' which the client supplies relating to its identity, as these can be altered by the client. You want to rely on the client's ssl certificate to provide the authentication of who the server is. To be honest if you're using things like hiera properly and avoiding huge hostname based if-blocks in your code (which you really should) you'll be fine.

2) It shouldn't be, assuming you keep it patched. Properly configured, there's only a small vector for the puppetmaster to be attacked by the clients. That said, the effects if it did get compromised are large, so take care to lock it down.

3) That's really a testing and deployment issue. If you have solid puppet code, it won't screw your files. It does take a little while to get that sorted, but for the basics (like you need) not long.

Answer (score 4):

> Is Puppet (or similar) a suitable technology for taking care of basic but critical mass changes?

Yes, it can be used this way.  I use it this to support external clients systems.

> I don't want any server to be able to see any config it shouldn't

If you are using puppet, you **must not** enable autosign then.  Autosign permits hosts to automatically request a certificate.  Your configuration and permissions will almost certainly be tied directly to the CN in the certificate.  You don't want random computer coming online and being able to claim that they are actually the system with all the secret high security stuff.

If you are really paranoid you can adjust the puppets fileserver settings to create shares that only some systems can access.  The fileserver access is based on the certificates.

> I don't want Puppet to make any changes which it shouldn't, or revert any manual changes done on the server.

There are a couple different approaches to permitting local changes.

One method I frequently use is below.  Basically if you pass an list to a `source`, then the puppet try each item in the list.  So I add the first item in the list to point at a local file.

```
  file { '/etc/ssh/sshd_config':
    ensure => present,
    source => ["/etc/ssh/sshd_config_local",
               "puppet:///modules/ssh/$ssh_config_file"],
    ...
  }
```

Another option would be to make use of symlinks.  If someone wants to use the puppet version they symlink to the puppet version of a file.  If they want maintain their config locally, then they don't create a symlink.

```
  file { '/etc/ssh/sshd_config_puppet':
    ensure => present,
    source => "puppet:///modules/ssh/$ssh_config_file",
    ...
  }
```

The other possibility is to use augeas to make line-level changes instead of changing entire files.  Be very conservative about what you change.

Answer (score 1):

3> There is no automatic undo in Puppet or in any such tools. You have to write explicit code to undo. Additionally, you can research the Environments feature of puppet, have a Testing lab where new code is tested (could be VMs), and use code review.

Comment: Not fully true. Chef makes a backup of any file it changes in `/var/lib/chef` by default (unless the resource is configured to leave no backups, e.g. for sensitive data), and with `doc` formatter you see a diff on the terminal output.

Comment: Well, yes, Puppet can make _multiple_ backups too. But how would you know which backup to restore? You would have to write some Chef/Puppet code, or external script to _actually perform_ that action? What about non-file resources like reverting to a previous package with a specific version? What about services? If you had code that said "ensure running", and wanted to change it, you would have to change the code to "ensure stopped".

Comment: The idea is that config management run is one-way. There is no supported rollback procedure, or fully functioning "dry run" (there is a whyrun mode in Chef that is only a suggestion / sanity check rather than full simulation (see http://blog.afistfulofservers.net/post/2012/12/21/promises-lies-and-dryrun-mode/ for a longer explanation). You can't un-change user password, etc.

This is why I wrote "not fully true" - there is no supported rollback, but there is a safety/debugging net that lets you see backup if something goes wrong and you need to take a look. Nothing more, but still useful.

Comment: And it turns out I've misread your comment - this is true that there is no automatic undo and you need to write explicit (and most likely faulty) code if you tried to automate it. I can't edit my original comment since it's been replied to - I was thinking about disaster recovery rather than automatic rollback. If you want to see automatic rollback, take a look at http://nixos.org/, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want Puppet to make any changes which it shouldn't, or revert
>   any manual changes done on the server.

For config files that are created using Puppets File type this can be achieved by setting:

```
replace => false,
```

I use that to generate some config files the first time that an application is deployed to a server, but then any edits to that config file won't be overwritten by Puppet.

However this does go against the philosophy of Puppet to be an idempotent deploy script.

It may be better if you can, to have separate admin-editable files which are not managed by puppet which are included from the files that are managed by puppet.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet works best for many servers with identical configuration. E.g. you write all the configuration of a shared web server provided by your company, then create N instances of that server. Afterwards doing changes on all instances at once (e.g. you find out that need to change AllowOverride for all apache virtual hosts) will be really easy. You'll also be able to store all the configuration information in a single place and have it under version control. In the perfect case you'll be able to handle a hardware failure by throwing away the broken host, replacing it with a new one, setting the same hostname and signing the needed certificate. Everything else could be done by Puppet.

But if you end up with almost no configuration sharing between two hosts, using puppet may be less productive than doing configuration manually. Also managing half of the server's configuration with puppet and the other half manually may not make much sense.

**Summary**: If you can create uniform and structured configuration for the hosts you're going to manage, Puppet is your best friend, but if you'll have to handle each service (host, virtual host, database) specially Puppet won't add much value.